# Angular2 Click Event on non-form elements

Tags: javascript, angular

This is about **Angular2**

How do I listen to events (like Click) on the non-form elements like `<li>`?

side-bar.html

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    {{title}}
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li *ng-for="#collection of collections" (click)="liClicked(this)">
            <a href="#">{{ collection }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

SideBarComponent

```
function SideBarComponent(){
    this.title = "Collections";
    this.collections = ["Collection-1", "Collection-2", "Collection-3", "Collection-4", "Collection-5"];
    this.liClicked = function(el){
        alert('a');
    }
}
SideBarComponent.annotations = [
    new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector:'side-bar'
    }),
    new angular.ViewAnnotation({
        templateUrl: 'templates/side-bar.html',
        directives:[angular.NgFor]
    })
];
```

A point to be noted here is that, if I replace `<a>` tag from side-bar.html with a `<button>` tag, the click event works fine. But for some reason, it doesn't work when I add `(click)` handler to `<li>` element.

Comment: Could you try to change your event as `liClicked (el: any) {
    alert('a');
  }`

Comment: Thank you for your resonse. I need JS code for this. I can't compile `ES6` code at my current machine due to organizational restrictions. :)

Comment: Have you tried with `(^click)`?

Answer (score 8):

I am not familiar with the es5 syntax for angular2, but the "this" you have in your li tag seems weird. Maybe you can try without the parameter in a first place. (click) should work on any element.

If you want to pass the html element the way to do it is : `<li #elem *ng-for="#collection of collections" (click)="liClicked(elem)">`

Answer (score 8):

As of angular2 is in beta now so according to updated version of angular there is syntax change like this:

> *ng-for changed to *ngFor

```
export class AppComponent { 
  collections: Array<any>= [];
  selected:string= null; 
  constructor(){
    this.collections = ["Collection-1", "Collection-2", "Collection-3", "Collection-4", "Collection-5"];
  }
  FunCalled(a){
    this.selected= a;
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

HTML part is:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    {{title}}
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li *ngFor="#collection of collections #i=index" (click)="FunCalled(collection)">
            <a href="#">{{ collection }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

Selected Value is : {{selected}}
```

and here is the example of working with  Angular2  Click Event on non-form elements here is the working example:
<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sGhDRFYQRLihe1s4WbnG?p=preview)</kbd>

## Update

`#` is not changed with `let` in the *ngFor. so the update syntax will be

```
*ngFor="let collection of collections; let i = index"
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to:

```
(click)="liClicked($event)"
```

Answer (score 3):

If your target element contains children, you may want to use the caret syntax for the click event to bubble (example):

```
<li (^click)="onClick($event)">
```

In your case it would be:

```
<li *ng-for="#collection of collections" (^click)="liClicked(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the click event on the "a" element instead of the "li" element, for example:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    {{title}}
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li *ngFor="#collection of collections #i=index">
            <a href="#" (click)="FunCalled(collection)">{{ collection }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```